# Why is the NETcdf data I created masked?

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I create a netcdf file with some data, and when I import the data in another script, it is masked :

```
    >>> type(Data[:])
    <class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray'>
```

Here is how I create the data :

```
    # Put in a grid
    print 'Putting the data in a grid...'
    LatRange = range( int(min(Lat)), int(max(Lat)), 1 )
    LonRange = np.arange( int(min(Lon)), int(max(Lon)), 1 )
    dRange = range(0,200,10) + range(200,4000,100)
    dateRange = np.arange( float(min(Dates).year)+min(Dates).month/12., float(max(Dates).year)+max(Dates).month/12., 1./12. )

    dataset = Dataset('gridded_data/DataAveraged.nc','w', format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC')
    zD = dataset.createDimension('zD',len(dRange))
    latD = dataset.createDimension('latD',len(LatRange))
    lonD = dataset.createDimension('lonD',len(LonRange))
    timeD = dataset.createDimension('timeD',len(dateRange))

    tempAve = dataset.createVariable('tempAve', np.float32, ('zD','latD','lonD','timeD'), fill_value=-9999)
    tempAve.units = 'psu'
    tempAve[:] = Tgrid_ave
```

Where Tgrid_ave is a numpy array.

Then, I import the data this way in another script :

```
    dataset = Dataset('gridded_data/DataAveraged.nc', 'r')

    LatRange = dataset.variables['lat'][:]
    LonRange = dataset.variables['lon'][:-1]

    Tgrid_ave = dataset.variables['tempAve']
```

And my Lat and Lon data are not masked, but my Tgrid_ave data is.

How can I avoid this!?

Comment: You can convert the masked `NumPy` array to ordinary array via `np.array(your_masked_array)`. You get the masked array as `Tgrid_ave` is probably masked array. I guess as you defined the fill value -9999 for your output netcdf file, `netCDF4` will automatically convert the output/input to masked array. So, where-ever you had missing data, it becomes filled with value -9999. In any case, just convert your input to ordinary array and perhaps replace the fill values with missing value: `datain=np.array(dataset.variables['tempAve'][:]);datain[datain==-9999]=np.nan`

Answer (score 2):

The netCDF4 library used to return either a masked array or a regular Numpy array, depending on if the data you request from the array (or array slice) contains fill values or not. This is unfortunate behavior but it seems to be fixed in [PR 787](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/pull/787). So I think that, from version 1.4 onward, the default behavior is always to return a masked array if a fill value is defined (I haven't tested it).

Anyway, you can ensure that you always get a regular numpy array by setting the [set_auto_mask](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.Variable.set_auto_mask)  to `False`.